# Disabling options in Chosen when checking a checkbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I'm using the Chosen library for a multiple select. It's working perfectly but my brain is stopping me from disabling certain options when a checkbox is checked.

Here is my fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/LukeMcLachlan/bturc6bq/**

The problem I'm facing is that when the checkbox is checked, the softwoods (class="softwoods") aren't being dynamically disabled, despite the fact that I'm doing what's suggested in the documentation (http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) in the section "Updating Chosen Dynamically", i.e. adding:

```
.trigger("chosen:updated");
```

does anyone familiar with chosen know what I'm doing wrong?

The strange thing is that if I just run the line:

```
$('.chosen-select').find('option.softwoods').prop('disabled', true);
```

then the softwood fields are disabled. It's just not working dynamically. Any help very much appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
The code now works perfectly. I got the following lines mixed around in the else statement:

```
if (!$("#checkbox3").is(":checked")) {    
  $('.chosen-select').find('option.softwoods').prop('disabled', true).trigger("chosen:updated");

} else {
  $('.chosen-select').find('option.softwoods').prop('disabled', false).trigger("chosen:updated");
}
```

and everything is working perfectly now. fiddle updated.

Comment: noticed that i got the true and false statements the wrong way round in my code, everything working perfectly now!

Answer (score 1):

Simple select you dropdown with jquery and use option:selected:

```
jQuery("#dropdown option:selected").prop('disabled', true);
```